# F# match with query results. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Tags: f#

I have an result of a JObject type, from parsing json:

```
let j = JObject.Parse x
```

the code I have to do is like:

```
if j = null then
    ... do stuff
else if j["aa"] <> null then
    ... do stuff
else if j["bb"] <> null then
    ... do stuff
else if j["cc"] <> null and j["dd"] <> null then
    ... do stuff
```

is there a clean way to do this match?

doing statements like

```
| _ when j.["error"] <> null ->
```

doesn't seem super clean. Can this be done better?

Comment: What objective thing(s) do you mean when you say "clean" and "better"? (Remember opinion-based questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow)

Comment: I suspect what they meant was "more idiomatic"

Comment: @VoronoiPotato put it right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create an active pattern that returns the matched `JToken`...

```
let (|NonNull|_|) prop (o : JObject) =
    o.[prop] |> Option.ofObj
```

you could write something like:

```
let handleAA (a : JToken) = ()

match JObject.Parse "{}" with
| null -> () // ...
| NonNull "aa" a -> handleAA a
| NonNull "bb" b & NonNull "cc" c -> ()
| _ -> () // all other
```

**Update**

If you need more power, Active Patterns galore...

```
let (|J|_|) prop (o : obj) =
    match o with
    | :? JObject as o -> o.[prop] |> Option.ofObj
    | _ -> None

let (|Deep|_|) (path : string) (o : obj) =
    let get t p = t |> Option.bind (fun t -> (``|J|_|``) p t)
    match o with
    | :? JToken as t ->
        path.Split('.') |> Array.fold get (Option.ofObj t)
    | _ -> None
```

... some helpers ...

```
let jV (t : JToken) = t.Value<string>()
let handle t = jV t |> printfn "single: %s"
let handle2 a b = printfn "(%s, %s)" (jV a) (jV b)
```

... a parse function ...

```
let parse o =
    match JsonConvert.DeserializeObject o with
    | null -> printfn "null"
    | J "aa" a -> handle a
    | J "bb" b & J "cc" c -> handle2 b c
    | J "bb" b & J "dd"  _ -> handle b
    | Deep "foo.bar" bar & Deep "hello.world" world -> handle2 bar world
    | Deep "foo.bar" bar -> handle bar
    | o -> printfn "val: %A" o
```

... and off we go:

```
parse "null" // null
parse "42" // val: 42L
parse "{ aa: 3.141 }" // single: 3.141
parse "{ bb: 2.718, cc: \"e\" }" // (2.718, e)
parse "{ bb: 2.718, dd: 0 }" // single: 2.718
parse "{ foo: { bar: \"baz\" } }" // single: baz
parse "{ foo: { bar: \"baz\" }, hello: { world: \"F#|>I❤\" } }" // (baz, F#|>I❤)
```

Comment: I think out of all the answers, this will work best; it's just syntactic sugar, but it'll help readability.

Comment: After looking again, it will not work because it doesn't allow chains: ["token1"]["token2"] you can test one token, or another, but not if token2, that can only exist if token1 exists, is present for example.

Comment: @Thomas please see me updated answer. Up to you to decide whether this is still `clean` ;-)

Comment: @Thomas the first version now shows how to combine cases. Also yet another update: the 'powerful' version is now much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

1. To do something for the first non-null value:

```
    let j = JObject.Parse x
    let doSomething s = printf "%A" s
    if isNull j then
        ()
    else
        [ j.["aa"]; j.["bb"]; j.["cc"] ]
        |> List.tryFind (fun s -> s |> Option.ofObj |> Option.isSome)
        |> doSomething
```

2. Or do something for each non-null value:

```
    let j = JObject.Parse x
    let doSomething s = printf "%A" s
    if isNull j then
        ()
    else
        [ j.["aa"]; j.["bb"]; j.["cc"] ]
        |> List.choose (fun s -> s |> Option.ofObj)
        |> List.iter doSomething
```

3. Or do something different (depending on which value is non-null) for the first non-null value:

```
    let j = JObject.Parse x
    let doSomethingA s = printf "%A" s
    let doSomethingB s = printf "%A" s
    let doSomethingC s = printf "%A" s
    if isNull j then
        ()
    else
        [ 
            j.["aa"], doSomethingA
            j.["bb"], doSomethingB
            j.["cc"], doSomethingC
        ]
        |> List.tryFind (fun (s, _) -> s |> Option.ofObj |> Option.isSome)
        |> Option.iter (fun (s, f) -> f s)
```

Comment: I'm afraid it would make it complicated to do scenarios where you have multiple combinations to check: this token and that token at the same time, etc

Answer (score 1):

You could create an active pattern to match non-null values...

```ml
let (|NonNull|_|) = function null -> None | v -> Some v
```

...which would allow the following.

```ml
if isNull j then
    //do stuff
else
    match j.["aa"], j.["bb"], j.["cc"], j.["dd"] with
    | NonNull aa, _, _, _ -> //do stuff
    | _, NonNull bb, _, _ -> //do stuff
    | _, _, NonNull cc, NonNull dd -> //do stuff
```

Comment: this could become very large quickly; the idea is good though, but I'm afraid it wouldn't improve readability after a few tokens.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a list of actions for each key so you could apply the null checking logic uniformly for each one.

```
let j = JObject.Parse x
let doStuff key value = printfn "%s=>%s" key value
```

If you wanted to apply doStuff for every key you could iterate though.  This is your example but without the else so it does it for every key present.

```
  ["aa", doStuff
   "bb", doStuff
   "cc", doStuff]
  |> List.iter (fun (key,action) -> 
    j.TryGetValue key
    |> snd
    |> Option.ofObj
    |> Option.iter (action key))
```

Matching your example more closely where you only doStuff for the first key present might use choose to get only the valid values,actions.

```
  ["aa", doStuff
   "bb", doStuff
   "cc", doStuff]
   |> Seq.choose (fun (key,action) ->
      j.TryGetValue key
      |> snd
      |> Option.ofObj
      |> Option.map (fun v -> action key v))
   |> Seq.tryHead
```

This version also returns the result of the applied doStuff if there was a matching key and doStuff returned a value.  This is abusing the lazy nature of Seq a little bit to only call the first value but you could also map to a function an call the result of Seq.tryHead.